# Finding conditions to make roots of a quadratic less than one in magnitude

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics

I'm doing a problem that asks for you to find the conditions that make $y$ defined:
$$y=x^2-bx+c$$
have real roots with magnitude less than one.

Now the condition for the roots being real seems to be: $$b^2\ge4c$$ The problem I have is finding the restrictions necessary for the second condition to be true, since intuitively it seems it should be that:
$$ \left|\frac{b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4c}}{2}\right|<1 \;\;\rightarrow\;\;\left|\,b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4c}\right|<2 $$
I'm not sure how to tackle the problem from here effectively (or indeed if this is the best way to tackle this type of question) since when I try to evaluate cases of the absolute value (using its definition) they seem to give contradictory results, for example I can't see where conditions that $|\,b\,|<2$ come from. From playing with Mathematica the answer it gives is:
$$ (-2 < b \leq 0\; \;\land\;\; -b - 1 < c \leq \frac{b^2}{4}) \;\;\lor \;\; (0 < b < 2 \;\;\land 
   \;\;b - 1 < c \leq \frac{b^2}{4}) $$
Which seems to make sense, at least trying values in those regions seem to work. I'm just wondering the best technique to tackle this kind of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a generic way to solve this classical problem:

*Find conditions on the coefficients of a quadratic polynomial $p(x)=ax^2+
bx+c$ so that it has two real roots between $x_0$  and $x_1$.*

1. A first condtiion is, of course, that it has two real roots: its discriminant $\Delta$ must be positive.
2. Let $\alpha<\beta\,$ be the real roots. A second condition is  that $x_0$ and $x_1$  must be outside the interval $[x_0, x_1]$. This means:
   $$ap(x_0)>0, \quad ap(x_1)>0 .$$
3. The last condition is that $\,x_0<\alpha$ and $\beta>x_1$. Knowing 2, this is equivalent to $$x_0<\dfrac{\alpha+\beta}2<x_1\iff x_0<-\frac b{2a}<x_1$$

In the present case, all this translates to:
$$  \begin{cases}
b^2>4c\\
b+c>-1,\quad b-c<1\\-2<b<2
\end{cases} $$

Graphical representation of the solutions as a domain of the plane:

[image]

Comment: (1) First of all, there is a typo and I believe it should be $ap(x_0) > 0$ instead. (2) After translating to the present case, I think your c is c, a = 1 and your b is –b. If this is so, $ap(–1) > 0$ should yield $b + c > –1$ instead. (3) I think the comma in the last-but-one statement means an ‘and’. If this is so, the un-shown detail is combining the two inequalities into one giving a simpler condition for c.

Comment: @Mick: Right. Thanks for pointing the typos! For the last point, we cannot have a simple condition. Instead, I'll add in a moment a graphical représentation of the set of points $(b,c)$ that satisfy all the conditions.

Comment: Right. The two inequalities should be interpreted the same way as those in Linear Programming. Great graph that illustrates your point.

Comment: Hehe! `pstricks` did it.

Comment: It is the first time I come across that. Delighted to learn drawings can be included in Tex.

Comment: I am not able to understand conditions 2 and 3. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 3):

A quick thought:
Let $y=(x-α)(x-β)$

Our roots are $x=α$ and $x=β$, and we want their magnitudes to be less than 1.

We also have $b=α+β$ and $c=αβ$.
If $|\,b\,|≥2$, we have $2≤|\,b\,|=|\,α+β\,|≤|\,α\,|+|\,β\,|$ so either $|\,α\,|≥1$ or $|\,β\,|≥1$.

For the condition on $c$, one comes from the discriminant as you mentioned, and you can get the other by looking at the graph of $y$ at $x=1$ and $x=-1$.